# using dictionary keys to access class attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I am building a GUI to modify the attributes of a collection of `Building` objects:

```
class Building:

    def __init__(self, company, addr):
        self.company = company
        self.addr = addr
```

Every time a new `Building` is highlighted in the GUI, various widgets should update to reflect that object's attributes.

I'd like to link each Building attribute to the widget that controls it. Maybe something along these lines:

```
attribute_widget_map = {
    'company': company_widget,
    'addr': addr:widget,
}
```

so that when I go to set the value of each widget, I can do it like this:

```
building = Building('XYZ', 'Anytown USA')
for attr, widget in attribute_widget_map.items():
    widget.set_value(building.__getattr__(attr))
```

My issue with this: I do not like that the keys in `attribute_widget_map` are string representations of `Building` properties. Say I change `addr` to `address`. The code will break. Is there any other way to do this than to rely on `__getattr__`?

What are the alternatives?

Comment: Either way if you change one, you have to change the other. No?

Comment: maybe my question should have been: is this an appropriate use of `__getattr__`?

Comment: That seems fine to me. Granted, maybe someone might come along and something else to say. But, looks good to me.

Comment: @idjaw thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

You could probably solve this with a variant of the [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#property) decorator:

```
class Bindings:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__bindings = []
    def bound_to(self, widget):
        def inner(func):
            prop = property(func)
            self.__bindings.append((prop, widget))
            return prop
        return inner
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.__bindings)

class Building:
    def __init__(self, address):
        self._address = address

    bindings = Bindings()

    @bindings.bound_to("address_widget")
    def address(self):
        return self._address

    @address.setter
    def address(self, value):
        self._address = value
```

Then you can have a function:

```
def update_widgets(building):
    for prop, widget in building.bindings:
        widget.value = prop.fget(building)
```

Using the following widget stub:

```
>>> class Widget:
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.name = name
...         Bindings.boundWidget['address'] = self
...     def update(self, value):
...         print(self.name, value)
...
```

-

```
>>> address_widget = Widget("Address widget")
>>> anySt = Building("123 Any Street")
>>> someAv = Building("42 Some Avenue")
>>>    
>>> update_widgets(anySt)
Address widget 123 Any Street
>>> update_widgets(someAv)
Address widget 42 Some Avenue
```